# How to efficiently add 2 linked lists of different sizes

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am having a problem with my function for adding two linked lists of different sizes together. They are already reversed. Everything this else seems to work, but i know the problem is in the while loop

```
 while(num1 != NULL && num2 != NULL)
```

when i use the && operator it only stops up to the end of the first finished list (I understand that). However when i try to use the or `(||)` operator my entire program just crashes. 
Can someone help me figure out what's wrong please.

this is the function. and my main.

```
//adds the two linked lists for their sum
node *addLargeNumber(node *num1, node *num2) {
    node *result = NULL;
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *temp;
    int sum, carry = 0;

    while(num1 != NULL || num2 != NULL) { //while both lists exists or either is not empty
        /*calculate values for the result. the next digit with be the sum of the carry
        from previous number(if any) digit from 1st list and digit from second list*/

        sum = carry + (num1->data) + (num2->data);                   
        if (sum > 9) carry = 1;
            else carry = 0;
        sum = sum % 10; //just want ones column from sum to put in result      
        temp = createNode(sum);

        if(result == NULL) 
            result = temp; //if it is first node, make it the head  
        else 
            prev->next = temp; //if not first node, connect it to rest
        prev = temp; //reset prev or next insertion

        // move to next nodes in both lists
        if(num1 != NULL) num1 = num1->next;
        if(num2 != NULL) num2 = num2->next;
    }

      if(carry > 0) temp->next = createNode(carry);        
      return result;
}
```

main function

```
int main(void) {
    node *storeNumber();
    void reverseList();
    void printList();
    node *addLargeNumber();
    node *add();

    char number1[numsize], number2[numsize], bigSum[numsize];
    node *top;
    char command;
    int number;

    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    while(fscanf(in, "%c", &command) != EOF) {   //while there are no more commands to be read
        top = NULL;  
        //adding two large numbers with linked list
        if(command == 'A') {
            fscanf(in, "%s", &number1);
            fscanf(in, "%s", &number2);   
            node *top1 = storeNumber(number1);
            node *top2 = storeNumber(number2);
            node *sum = addLargeNumber(top1, top2);

            printList(top1);
            printf("  +  ");
            printList(top2);
            printf("  =  ");
            printList(sum);
            printf("\n\n");
            fscanf(in, "%c", &command); 
        }
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: if you use `||`  "or" operator, one of num may be null, and the program crashes as you try to access `num1->data` or `num2->data`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

after trying to better understand what you are trying to do, I think you need to add a carry > 0 with an OR clause in your while loop.  I also think that you need to add each data element completely separately into the digit's sum checking for null prior to adding.  by doing these two things, you should continue adding nodes past your initial data if indeed the carry needs to be pushed past (or to the left) of your sum.

I think the below should work and you can take out the last two lines of your routine checking for the carry after the loop.  As an answer to WHY it was failing, it is the NON-CHECKING for NULL when performing your addition.  If you have one number longer than another, you aren't performing NULL checking prior to your addition, and this is causing the crash.

```
// while both lists exists or either is not empty
while(num1 != NULL || num2 != NULL || carry > 0){

    /*calculate values for the result. the next digit with be the sum of the carry
    from previous number(if any) digit from 1st list and digit from second list*/

    // Add in each element separately do detect for NULL on the fly
    sum = carry;
    if(num1->data != NULL) sum += num1-data;        
    if(num2->data != NULL) sum += num2-data;

    // Test to see if we should carry
    if (sum > 9) carry = 1;
        else carry = 0;

    // Lets keep the remainder as the value for this particular digit of the sum
    sum = sum % 10; //just want ones column from sum to put in result
    temp = createNode(sum);

    if(result == NULL) 
        result = temp; //if it is first node, make it the head  
    else 
        prev->next = temp; //if not first node, connect it to rest
    prev = temp; //reset prev or next insertion

    // move to next nodes in both lists
    if(num1 != NULL) num1 = num1->next;
    if(num2 != NULL) num2 = num2->next;
}
```

Try this:

```
// Changed this from || to && so that either of them will force a 
// stop in the looping
while(num1 != NULL && num2 != NULL) {

    ......

    // move to next nodes in both lists - Changed these two lines to force the null
    // to pop out within the while loop checking
    num1 = num1->next;
    num2 = num2->next;
}
```

You need to change the || or to an and && because the while loop is going to continue while EITHER of them are null.  Further though you need to force their movement to the next value without checking for NULL at the end.  Without MOVING into the null, the while loop will never get to a null point, and thus you are creating an endless loop.

It should also be noted that you don't need the if statements protecting the bottom two most lines within your main adder loop because this coverage is taken care of by your loop checking if done right.

Comment: hi, I used the && operator and outside the while loop I used if statements for the remainder of a list 
          
for example
          if (num1 == NULL && num2 != NULL) {
               temp->next = num2;
               return result;
          } 
the only problem i get now is if there is a carry its not being added to the result

Answer (score 0):

if you use `||` "or" operator, one of num may be null, and the program crashes as you try to access `num1->data` or `num2->data`

Try something like :

```
 sum = carry;
 if(num1 != NULL) sum += num1->data;
 if(num2 != NULL) sum += num2->data;
```

and

```
 if(num1!= NULL) num1 = num1->next;
 if(num2!= NULL) num2 = num2->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the program. Ensure that "there may be infinite nodes" so that it may not reach end. If all are correct, there may be some problem due to short-circuit property of operators. There may be some problem with increment of nodes also, check that too. In that case, try NESTED WHILE statement.
        while(num1!=NULL)
        {
        while(num2!=NULL)
        {
        /* ...............
        ..................
        ...............*/
        }
        }